# WPF animation won't repeat

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

There is an MSDN article that specifically addresses my question but it does not provide a solution in my case:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I want to trigger an animation from my view model where I fade out one textblock and subsequently fade in another textblock to appear like the text is updating.  I need to run this animation 3 times in a row.  It would be nice if I could just set the Animate property to "On" 3 times in a row and it would start the animation repeatedly but this does not seem to work.

The next best option would be to notify my ViewModel when the animation is complete allowing me to set the Animate property to "Off" and then change it back to "On".  This doesnt seem to work for 2 reasons.  If "Off" and "On" are set in the same method call the View doesnt seem to update the property until after that threads method execution is complete.  And the second problem is that the Completed event of the animation is **NEVER CALLED**...this is something that is a constant issue for me.

Any other suggestions?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Animate}" Value="On">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Show one textblock and hide the other -->
                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtMessage"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtMessage2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0" />

                    <!-- Now animate the text blocks back to their original setting -->
                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtMessage"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                            Completed="Animation_Completed" />
                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtMessage2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                            BeginTime="0:0:1"
                            Completed="Animation_Completed" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Again, for some reason the Animation_Completed handler is never hit...

**Updated 5/8 to spell out more specifically what I need this animation to do.**

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is, as your XAML works well for me. The animations do actually run each time the `Animate` property changes to `On`. Are you sure that you ever reset it to any other value than `On`?

Comment: Looks like that might be right.  I tried changing the property to off then turning it back to on in the same method call so the view might not be updating because of threading issues...anyway to force the view to update immediately after setting it to off?